# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException when connecting to remote server

Tags: java, android, json

Since my app works perfectly with xampp local server , i'm trying to connect with a remote web server . I uploaded my sql database and php files. Problem is that i get 
" Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".  Json response includes general informations about host server.
Any idea;

Comment: Show us the relevant code please.

Comment: what code do you mean; This is a general problem since my app works on local server

Comment: I mean the portion of code where the error happened. And maybe the stack trace too.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an HTML page in response instead of JSON. (The HTML page starts with the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.) You are either calling an invalid URL or your server is responding with an error page.